# Handle frontend-backend authentication using ethers js

Tags: ethers.js, authentication

### Context:

My dapp has 3 components: **frontend** (React), **backend** (Solidity) and **storage** (Node+MongoDb). The storage is needed to store info that will be used in the future.

Frontend-Storage communication needs some sort of authentication to make sure that User 0xABC is adding/modifying data that belongs to user 0xABC.

### Question:

Is it possible to use the fact that the user wallet is connected with the app to **generate an authentication header that will be sent with all requests and verified** by the storage?

Bonus points: with ether.js? :D

Comment: hi did you work this out ? I have got so far as getting the signed message client side, but not sure how verify storage side

Comment: @NimChimpsky see the answer. Feel free to ask more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Backend

In the backend (in my case it's called `storage`), I've added the following endpoints:

- `/message-to-sign/:userAddress` -> creates a message that the user will sign with their Metamask, containing the user address and an OTP to prevent replay attacks. When the OTP is generated, we save it locally, so when `login` is called, we verify the OTP for that address.

```js
    const message = composeMessage(userAddress, otp);
    return res.json({ message });
```

- `/login` -> The signed message is sent over and verified. If it matches, the user is authenticated.

```js
    const message = composeMessage(userAddress, otp);
    const decodedAddress = utils.verifyMessage(message, signedMessage);

    if (userAddress !== decodedAddress) {
        return res.status(403).send("Invalid signature");
    }

    // generate JWT and send back
    const authToken = jwt.sign({ userAddress }, process.env.JWT_SECRET as string, { expiresIn: '2592000s' });
    res.cookie('token', authToken, { httpOnly: true, secure: true });
    return res.send();
```

### Frontend

In the frontend we

1. get the message to be signed
2. get the user to sign it with their wallet
3. send back the signed message
4. if the request works, the user will be logged in

```js
async function triggerLogin(walletAddress: string): Promise<void> {
    const message = await getLoginMessage(walletAddress); // call /message-to-sign/:userAddress
    const signedMessage = await signMessage(message);
    await login(walletAddress, signedMessage); // call /login
}

async function signMessage(message: string): Promise<any> {
    const ethers = require('ethers');
    const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider((window as any).ethereum);
    const signer = provider.getSigner();
    const signature = await signer.signMessage(message);
    return signature;
}
```

I've taken inspiration from debank.com to create the login system.